# My graphql query resolvers are not running parallelly using hotchoclate

Tags: parallel-processing, graphql

When I print the execution start time of both resolvers ,I can see the end time of 1st resolver is the start time of 2nd resolver.
Should I do any configuration to force parallel execution of my resolvers.

Query

Resolver1
A
B
Resolver 2
C
D

Am expecting start time of both resolver to be same are atleast before the end time of first resolver so that I can showcase my query resolvers hav ran in parallel